# Change 2nd parameter of method 'PlaceAutocompleteAdapter' from 'GeoDataClient' to 'GoogleApiClient'

Tags: google-api-client, autocompletetextview, android-googleapiclient

i ma making AutoCompleteTextView in my adapter for which when i make object of PlaceAutocompleteAdapter when i pass GoogleApiClient object as second parameter to my PlaceAutocompleteAdapter it gives me red error and sys to pass GEODataClient object instead of GoogleApiClient

[image]

[image]

while the code for my Fragment containing map is this

```
package com.example.anonymous.ghar_ka_khana;

import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Address;
import android.location.Geocoder;
import android.location.Location;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.FusedLocationProviderClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.Places;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLngBounds;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import android.Manifest;
import android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.concurrent.Executor;


public class GoogleFragment extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback,LocationListener,GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {


    private MapFragment m;
    private GoogleMap mMap;
    FusedLocationProviderClient fusedLocationProviderClient;
    private int REQUEST_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE = 125;

    protected Location mLastLocation;
    private AutoCompleteTextView autoCompleteTextView;
    private PlaceAutocompleteAdapter autocompleteAdapter;


    private String mLatitiudelabel;
    private String mLongitudelabel;

    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

    private static LatLngBounds Lat_Long_Bounds = new LatLngBounds(new LatLng(-40,-168),new LatLng(71,136));
    View v;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {

        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        Log.i("pahlywala", "onCreateView");
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_google, container, false);
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient
                .Builder(getActivity())
                .addApi(Places.GEO_DATA_API)
                .addApi(Places.PLACE_DETECTION_API)
                .enableAutoManage(new DrawerActivity(), this)
                .build();
        autoCompleteTextView = (AutoCompleteTextView)v.findViewById(R.id.mapsearch);
        autocompleteAdapter = new PlaceAutocompleteAdapter(getActivity(),mGoogleApiClient,Lat_Long_Bounds,null);
        autoCompleteTextView.setAdapter(autocompleteAdapter);
        return  v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        mLatitiudelabel = "Latitude";
        mLongitudelabel = "Longitude";

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getFragmentManager();
        final MapFragment myMapFragment = (MapFragment) fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.googlemap);
        myMapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
        Log.i("pahlywalass", "onViewCreated");

        fusedLocationProviderClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(getActivity());
    }


    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap)
    {
        mMap=googleMap;
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(new LatLng(0, 0))
                .title("Marker"));
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        if (!checkPermissions()) {
            requestPermissions();
        } else {
            getLastLocation();
        }
    }

    private boolean checkPermissions() {
        int permissionState = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(),
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
        return permissionState == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
    }

    private void requestPermissions() {
        boolean shouldProvideRationale =
                ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(getActivity(),
                        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);

        // Provide an additional rationale to the user. This would happen if the user denied the
        // request previously, but didn't check the "Don't ask again" checkbox.
        if (shouldProvideRationale) {
            Log.i("displaying permission", "Displaying permission rationale to provide additional context.");

           /* showSnackbar("warning", android.R.string.ok,
                    new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {
                            // Request permission
                            startLocationPermissionRequest();
                        }
                    });*/

        } else {
            Log.i("requesting permission", "Requesting permission");
            // Request permission. It's possible this can be auto answered if device policy
            // sets the permission in a given state or the user denied the permission
            // previously and checked "Never ask again".
            startLocationPermissionRequest();
        }
    }

    private void startLocationPermissionRequest() {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(new DrawerActivity(),
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                REQUEST_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions,
                                           @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        Log.i("onRequestPerm", "onRequestPermissionResult");
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE) {
            if (grantResults.length <= 0) {
                // If user interaction was interrupted, the permission request is cancelled and you
                // receive empty arrays.
                Log.i("onRequestPerm", "User interaction was cancelled.");
            } else if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // Permission granted.
                getLastLocation();
            } else {
                // Permission denied.

                // Notify the user via a SnackBar that they have rejected a core permission for the
                // app, which makes the Activity useless. In a real app, core permissions would
                // typically be best requested during a welcome-screen flow.

                // Additionally, it is important to remember that a permission might have been
                // rejected without asking the user for permission (device policy or "Never ask
                // again" prompts). Therefore, a user interface affordance is typically implemented
                // when permissions are denied. Otherwise, your app could appear unresponsive to
                // touches or interactions which have required permissions.
                /*showSnackbar(R.string.textwarn, R.string.settings,
                        new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View view) {
                                // Build intent that displays the App settings screen.
                                Intent intent = new Intent();
                                intent.setAction(
                                        Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);
                                Uri uri = Uri.fromParts("package",
                                        BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID, null);
                                intent.setData(uri);
                                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                                startActivity(intent);
                            }
                        });*/
            }
        }
    }

    private void getLastLocation() {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        }
        fusedLocationProviderClient.getLastLocation()
                .addOnCompleteListener(getActivity(), new OnCompleteListener<Location>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Location> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful() && task.getResult() != null) {

                            mLastLocation = task.getResult();

                            Log.i("Longitutde", mLastLocation.getLongitude()+"");
                            Log.i("Longitutde", mLastLocation.getLatitude()+"");

                            LatLng cur_Latlng=new LatLng(mLastLocation.getLatitude(),mLastLocation.getLongitude()); // giving your marker to zoom to your location area.
                            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                                    .position(cur_Latlng)
                                    .title("umair"));
                            mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(cur_Latlng));
                            mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(12));

                            Geocoder geocoder;
                            List<Address> addresses = null;
                            geocoder = new Geocoder(getActivity(), Locale.getDefault());

                            try {
                                addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(mLastLocation.getLatitude(),mLastLocation.getLongitude(), 1); // Here 1 represent max location result to returned, by documents it recommended 1 to 5
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                            String address = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0); // If any additional address line present than only, check with max available address lines by getMaxAddressLineIndex()
                            String city = addresses.get(0).getLocality();
                            /*String state = addresses.get(0).getAdminArea();
                            String country = addresses.get(0).getCountryName();
                            String postalCode = addresses.get(0).getPostalCode();
                            String knownName = addresses.get(0).getFeatureName();*/

                            Log.i("pat", ""+city);


                        }
                        else {
                            Log.i("getlasts", "getLastLocation:exception", task.getException());

                        }
                    }
                });
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

    }
}
```

while the code for PlaceAutoCompleteAdapter is following

```
package com.example.anonymous.ghar_ka_khana;

/**
 * Created by Anonymous on 2/19/2018.
 */

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.text.style.CharacterStyle;
import android.text.style.StyleSpan;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Filter;
import android.widget.Filterable;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.google.android.gms.common.data.DataBufferUtils;
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.AutocompleteFilter;
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.AutocompletePrediction;
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.AutocompletePredictionBufferResponse;
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.GeoDataClient;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLngBounds;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.RuntimeExecutionException;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Tasks;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException;

/**
 * Adapter that handles Autocomplete requests from the Places Geo Data Client.
 * {@link AutocompletePrediction} results from the API are frozen and stored directly in this
 * adapter. (See {@link AutocompletePrediction#freeze()}.)
 */
public class PlaceAutocompleteAdapter
        extends ArrayAdapter<AutocompletePrediction> implements Filterable {

    private static final String TAG = "PlaceAutocompleteAd";
    private static final CharacterStyle STYLE_BOLD = new StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD);
    /**
     * Current results returned by this adapter.
     */
    private ArrayList<AutocompletePrediction> mResultList;

    /**
     * Handles autocomplete requests.
     */
    private GeoDataClient mGeoDataClient;

    /**
     * The bounds used for Places Geo Data autocomplete API requests.
     */
    private LatLngBounds mBounds;

    /**
     * The autocomplete filter used to restrict queries to a specific set of place types.
     */
    private AutocompleteFilter mPlaceFilter;

    /**
     * Initializes with a resource for text rows and autocomplete query bounds.
     *
     * @see android.widget.ArrayAdapter#ArrayAdapter(android.content.Context, int)
     */
    public PlaceAutocompleteAdapter(Context context, GeoDataClient geoDataClient,
                                    LatLngBounds bounds, AutocompleteFilter filter) {
        super(context, android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_2, android.R.id.text1);
        mGeoDataClient = geoDataClient;
        mBounds = bounds;
        mPlaceFilter = filter;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the bounds for all subsequent queries.
     */
    public void setBounds(LatLngBounds bounds) {
        mBounds = bounds;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the number of results received in the last autocomplete query.
     */
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mResultList.size();
    }

    /**
     * Returns an item from the last autocomplete query.
     */
    @Override
    public AutocompletePrediction getItem(int position) {
        return mResultList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

        // Sets the primary and secondary text for a row.
        // Note that getPrimaryText() and getSecondaryText() return a CharSequence that may contain
        // styling based on the given CharacterStyle.

        AutocompletePrediction item = getItem(position);

        TextView textView1 = (TextView) row.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
        TextView textView2 = (TextView) row.findViewById(android.R.id.text2);
        textView1.setText(item.getPrimaryText(STYLE_BOLD));
        textView2.setText(item.getSecondaryText(STYLE_BOLD));

        return row;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the filter for the current set of autocomplete results.
     */
    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        return new Filter() {
            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
                FilterResults results = new FilterResults();

                // We need a separate list to store the results, since
                // this is run asynchronously.
                ArrayList<AutocompletePrediction> filterData = new ArrayList<>();

                // Skip the autocomplete query if no constraints are given.
                if (constraint != null) {
                    // Query the autocomplete API for the (constraint) search string.
                    filterData = getAutocomplete(constraint);
                }

                results.values = filterData;
                if (filterData != null) {
                    results.count = filterData.size();
                } else {
                    results.count = 0;
                }

                return results;
            }

            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {

                if (results != null && results.count > 0) {
                    // The API returned at least one result, update the data.
                    mResultList = (ArrayList<AutocompletePrediction>) results.values;
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                } else {
                    // The API did not return any results, invalidate the data set.
                    notifyDataSetInvalidated();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public CharSequence convertResultToString(Object resultValue) {
                // Override this method to display a readable result in the AutocompleteTextView
                // when clicked.
                if (resultValue instanceof AutocompletePrediction) {
                    return ((AutocompletePrediction) resultValue).getFullText(null);
                } else {
                    return super.convertResultToString(resultValue);
                }
            }
        };
    }

    /**
     * Submits an autocomplete query to the Places Geo Data Autocomplete API.
     * Results are returned as frozen AutocompletePrediction objects, ready to be cached.
     * Returns an empty list if no results were found.
     * Returns null if the API client is not available or the query did not complete
     * successfully.
     * This method MUST be called off the main UI thread, as it will block until data is returned
     * from the API, which may include a network request.
     *
     * @param constraint Autocomplete query string
     * @return Results from the autocomplete API or null if the query was not successful.
     * @see GeoDataClient#getAutocompletePredictions(String, LatLngBounds, AutocompleteFilter)
     * @see AutocompletePrediction#freeze()
     */
    private ArrayList<AutocompletePrediction> getAutocomplete(CharSequence constraint) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Starting autocomplete query for: " + constraint);

        // Submit the query to the autocomplete API and retrieve a PendingResult that will
        // contain the results when the query completes.
        Task<AutocompletePredictionBufferResponse> results =
                mGeoDataClient.getAutocompletePredictions(constraint.toString(), mBounds,
                        mPlaceFilter);

        // This method should have been called off the main UI thread. Block and wait for at most
        // 60s for a result from the API.
        try {
            Tasks.await(results, 60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        } catch (ExecutionException | InterruptedException | TimeoutException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            AutocompletePredictionBufferResponse autocompletePredictions = results.getResult();

            Log.i(TAG, "Query completed. Received " + autocompletePredictions.getCount()
                    + " predictions.");

            // Freeze the results immutable representation that can be stored safely.
            return DataBufferUtils.freezeAndClose(autocompletePredictions);
        } catch (RuntimeExecutionException e) {
            // If the query did not complete successfully return null
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Error contacting API: " + e.toString(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.e(TAG, "Error getting autocomplete prediction API call", e);
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

my gradle file is following

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.anonymous.ghar_ka_khana"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.8.0'
    //11.0.4
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:3.1.3'
    // FirebaseUI for Firebase Auth
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:3.1.3'
    // FirebaseUI for Firebase Realtime Database
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-firestore:3.1.3'
    // FirebaseUI for Cloud Firestore
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:11.8.0'
    //Firestore dependency
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-storage:3.1.3'
    // FirebaseUI for Cloud Storage
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-login:4.29.0'
    // Required only if Facebook login support is required
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
    implementation 'com.github.florent37:materialtextfield:1.0.7'
    compile 'com.scalified:fab:1.1.3'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:11.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.8.0'
    compile 'com.github.glomadrian:Grav:1.1'
    implementation('com.mikepenz:materialdrawer:6.0.6@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
    compile 'com.wdullaer:materialdatetimepicker:3.5.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.8.0'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
        def requested = details.requested
        if (requested.group == 'com.android.support') {
            if (!requested.name.startsWith("multidex")) {
                details.useVersion '26.1.0'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I've got the solution instead of using:

```
 autocompleteAdapter = new PlaceAutocompleteAdapter(getActivity(),mGoogleApiClient,Lat_Long_Bounds,null);
```

you will have to use:

```
autocompleteAdapter = new PlaceAutocompleteAdapter(getActivity(),Places.getGeoDataClient(getActivity(), null),Lat_Long_Bounds,null);
```